# Aligning equations in multiple enumerate items of form "text : equation"

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, enumerate, alignment

I have the following code / attempt:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item bla bla bla: $\begin{aligned} a   &= 3    \end{aligned}$
    \item bla:  $\begin{aligned} b  &= 2    \end{aligned}$
    \item bla bla bla $\eqmakebox[mm][r]{$c$} = hm$
    \item $\eqmakebox[mm][r]{$d$} = ah$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to make the = align across the different items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

With `tabular` table:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rownum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\stepcounter{rownum}\therownum.}r @{\ } l>{$}r<{$} @{\,} >{$}l<{$}}
    &  bla bla bla:  & a & = 3      \\
    &  bla:          & b & = 2      \\
    &  bla bla bla:  & c & = hm     \\
    &                & d & = ah     \\ 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```